# android httpclient and utf-8

Tags: android, utf-8, httpclient, http-get

I'm trying to connect to a webservice where my querysting holds some data. The bad thing is that this data contains utf-8 charcters, which renders a problem.

If I simply call HttpGet with the ordinary string I get the "illegal character" exception. So I googled and tried some utf-8 magic.

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");
        String utfurl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(utfurl);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getInputStream: " +e.getMessage());
```

Now I won't get the illegal charcter, but it seem to mess upp the utfurl completely since I instead get the "target host must not be null, or set in parameters". Probably because he doesnt recognize the "http://" part in a messed up string.
Any advice?

Regards

Comment: Is it the *URL* which needs to contain UTF-8-encoded characters (which would be odd, I think) or the content returned by the web server?

Comment: I agree with jon, and your current approach will be encoding the `:` and `/` characters and is breaking your url.

Comment: the URL needs to contain urf-8 charcters, it's calling a webservice and holds data in the querystring, not very good if you ask me but that's how it's done. And yes, I noticed the :/ signs are corrupted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want a URL encoded query string.  If so, use:

```
String query = "?param=value";
String host = "http://my.host.name.com/";
String encodedUrl = host + UrlEncoder.encode(query,"utf-8");
```

The basic idea is that you only want to encode the query string, not the host name or protocol.