# IllegalArgumentException in Java URI

Tags: java, android, url

I want to create HttpPost request like that:

```
http://site/searches.json -d"search[params_attributes[origin_name]=MOW"\ -d"search[params_attributes][destination_name]=IEV"\ -d"search[params_attributes[some]=SOME"
```

I tried it by hand - works fine.
But I have error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 43:  http://somesite/searches.json -d"search[params_attributes][origin_name]=KBP"...
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:776)
at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
```

It says that error is in first space position.
Any ideas?

Edited:

I tried:

```
mMethodURI = URLEncoder.encode(mMethodURI, "UTF-8");
```

And get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:572)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:292)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Comment: [Solved.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989743/android-httpclient-and-utf-8)
The problem was in unexpected place:)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    URLEncoder.encode(url);
    URLDecoder.decode(url);
```

to encode and decode your url.

Try using following code and make sure all permissions are set in manifest file.

```
public String executeUrl(String url, Context context) 
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    String result = null;

    try
    {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if(httpEntity != null)
        {
            InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            result = Parser.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException eUnknownHostException) 
    {
        eUnknownHostException.printStackTrace();
        result = null;
    }
    catch(ConnectTimeoutException eConnectTimeoutException) 
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
}



private String convertStreamToString(InputStream ipStream)
{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ipStream), 8192);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n"); 
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioException)
    {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            ipStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException)
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: HttpPost request = new HttpPost(mMethodURI);
HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(request);
error is in first line

Comment: all permissions are setted, it worked nice until I thy this url. The problem is in the url.

Comment: ok... next time paste url in browser and if its correct then only move forward for coding

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15120/discussion-between-basavaraj-and-metalex)

Comment: there is a problem. I cannnot try the link in browser, becouse it is a POST method.